# Group Child Nodes based on Specific Condition

Tags: xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0, xslt-grouping

I have been having trouble transforming below xml using XSLT 2.0. Could anyone help me resolve this please? Thanks

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <Row>
        <EmployeeID>88888</EmployeeID>
        <Remote/>
        <StartDate>2014-10-19</StartDate>
        <EndDate>2021-10-08</EndDate>
        <Amount>100</Amount>
        <BasePay>760</BasePay>
        <Bonus>340</Bonus>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <EmployeeID>12345</EmployeeID>
        <Remote/>
        <StartDate>2017-10-10</StartDate>
        <EndDate>2018-10-10</EndDate>
        <Amount>250</Amount>
        <BasePay>1500</BasePay>
        <Bonus>150</Bonus>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <EmployeeID>23456</EmployeeID>
        <Remote>N</Remote>
        <StartDate/>
        <EndDate></EndDate>
        <Amount></Amount>
        <BasePay>1500</BasePay>
        <Bonus>150</Bonus>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <EmployeeID>23456</EmployeeID>
        <Remote>N</Remote>
        <StartDate/>
        <EndDate>2020-10-10</EndDate>
        <Amount>2400</Amount>
        <BasePay>1500</BasePay>
        <Bonus/>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <EmployeeID>23456</EmployeeID>
        <Remote>N</Remote>
        <StartDate>2018-10-24</StartDate>
        <EndDate>2020-10-10</EndDate>
        <Amount>2400</Amount>
        <BasePay>1500</BasePay>
        <Bonus/>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <EmployeeID>12345</EmployeeID>
        <Remote/>
        <StartDate>2017-10-10</StartDate>
        <EndDate>2018-10-10</EndDate>
        <Amount>350</Amount>
        <BasePay>1600</BasePay>
        <Bonus>170</Bonus>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <EmployeeID>65432</EmployeeID>
        <Remote>Y</Remote>
        <StartDate/>
        <EndDate></EndDate>
        <Amount></Amount>
        <BasePay>1500</BasePay>
        <Bonus>150</Bonus>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <EmployeeID>65432</EmployeeID>
        <Remote>Y</Remote>
        <StartDate>2021-10-25</StartDate>
        <EndDate>2020-10-10</EndDate>
        <Amount>8400</Amount>
        <BasePay>1500</BasePay>
        <Bonus/>
    </Row>
</Root>
```

**Desired Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <Row>
        <EmployeeID>88888</EmployeeID>
        <Remote/>
        <StartDate>2014-10-19</StartDate>
        <EndDate>2021-10-08</EndDate>
        <Amount>100</Amount>
        <BasePay>760</BasePay>
        <Bonus>340</Bonus>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <EmployeeID>12345</EmployeeID>
        <Remote/>
        <StartDate>2017-10-10</StartDate>
        <EndDate>2018-10-10</EndDate>
        <Amount>250</Amount>
        <BasePay>1500</BasePay>
        <Bonus>150</Bonus>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <EmployeeID>23456</EmployeeID>
        <Remote>N</Remote>
        <StartDate>2018-10-24</StartDate>
        <EndDate>2020-10-10</EndDate>
        <Amount>2400</Amount>
        <BasePay>1500</BasePay>
        <Bonus>150</Bonus>
    </Row>  
    <Row>
        <EmployeeID>12345</EmployeeID>
        <Remote/>
        <StartDate>2017-10-10</StartDate>
        <EndDate>2018-10-10</EndDate>
        <Amount>350</Amount>
        <BasePay>1600</BasePay>
        <Bonus>170</Bonus>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <EmployeeID>65432</EmployeeID>
        <Remote>Y</Remote>
        <StartDate>2021-10-25</StartDate>
        <EndDate>2020-10-10</EndDate>
        <Amount>8400</Amount>
        <BasePay>1500</BasePay>
        <Bonus>150</Bonus>
    </Row>    
</Root>
```

Grouping needs to be based on `<Remote>` element with value either Y or N.

For e.g. Employee 23456 appears thrice in the input xml with `<Remote>`set to N – Result xml is expected to have Employee 23456 only once but expected to pick up values for `StartDate`(i.e 2018-10-24) `EndDate` (i.e 2020-10-10) `Amount`(i.e. 2400)

For e.g. Employee 65432 appears twice in the input xml with value `<Remote>` set to Y – Result xml is expected to have Employee 65432 only once but expected to pick up values for `StartDate` (i.e 2021-10-25) `EndDate` (i.e 2020-10-10) `Amount` (8400)

Employee 12345 appears twice in the input xml with blank value for `<Remote>` - Result xml is expected to have Employee 12345 twice because `<BasePay>` and `<Bonus>` amounts are different.

Below is my attempt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"></xsl:output>
        
       <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
        
      <xsl:template match="/Root">
          <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:for-each-group select="Row" group-by="EmployeeID/[Mobile='Y' or 'N']">
                <Row>
                    <EmployeeID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="EmployeeID"/>
                    </EmployeeID>
                    <Remote>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Remote"/>
                    </Remote>
                    <StartDate>
                        <xsl:value-of select="StartDate"/>
                    </StartDate>
                    <EndDate>
                        <xsl:value-of select="EndDate"/>
                    </EndDate>
                    <Amount>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Amount"/>
                    </Amount>
                    <BasePay>
                        <xsl:value-of select="BasePay"/>
                    </BasePay>
                    <Bonus>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Bonus"/>
                    </Bonus>                    
                </Row>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
          </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What is `Is_Mobile='Y' or 'N'` testing for if the text speaks about `Remote` being `Y` or `N`? Do you want to simply group all `Row`s which have `Remote` set to `N` or `Y` by `EmployeeID` and push through other `Row`s (i.e. the ones with an empty `Remote` or different to `N` or `Y` without grouping?

Comment: <Is_Mobile> was a typing error, apologies. <Mobile> is the correct name of the element. I want to group all <Rows> which have Remote set to N or Y by EmployeeID and push through other Rows(i.e with empty Remote). For <Rows> which have Remote set to N or Y, it’s possible that few of the sibling elements may be empty ( for e.g.  EmployeeID 23456 appears thrice in the input xml, first occurrence of 23456 have <StartDate> and <Bonus> are empty, but result XML is expected to have <StartDate> and <Bonus> values picked up from second occurrence or third occurrence of EmployeeID 23456.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps (using a composite grouping key as possible in XSLT 3)

```
  <xsl:template match="/Root">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="Row" composite="yes" group-by="EmployeeID, Remote = ('Y', 'N')">
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()[2]">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

Or using a composite key and then a match pattern that removes/strips the duplicates is easier to preserve the original order:

```
  <xsl:key name="group" match="Root/Row" composite="yes" use="EmployeeID, Remote = ('Y', 'N')"/>

  <xsl:template match="Root/Row[. intersect key('group', (EmployeeID, true()))[position() > 1]]"/>
  
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
```

As for your comment about empty children, perhaps

```
  <xsl:template match="Root/Row[. intersect key('group', (EmployeeID, true()))[1]]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="key('group', (EmployeeID, true()))/*[node()]" group-by="node-name()">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

ensures the non-empty child elements in a group of `Row`s are output instead of the child elements of the first item in a group.

An [online sample is here](https://xsltfiddle-beta.liberty-development.net/?xslt=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%0D%0A%20%20expand-text%3D%22yes%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20method%3D%22xml%22%20indent%3D%22yes%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Amode%20on-no-match%3D%22shallow-copy%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Akey%20name%3D%22group%22%20match%3D%22Root%2FRow%22%20composite%3D%22yes%22%20use%3D%22EmployeeID%2C%20Remote%20%3D%20%28%27Y%27%2C%20%27N%27%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22Root%2FRow%5B.%20intersect%20key%28%27group%27%2C%20%28EmployeeID%2C%20true%28%29%29%29%5Bposition%28%29%20%3E%201%5D%5D%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22Root%2FRow%5B.%20intersect%20key%28%27group%27%2C%20%28EmployeeID%2C%20true%28%29%29%29%5B1%5D%5D%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acopy%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Afor-each-group%20select%3D%22key%28%27group%27%2C%20%28EmployeeID%2C%20true%28%29%29%29%2F*%5Bnode%28%29%5D%22%20group-by%3D%22node-name%28%29%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22.%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Afor-each-group%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Acopy%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0D%0A&input=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3CRoot%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CRow%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CEmployeeID%3E88888%3C%2FEmployeeID%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CRemote%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CStartDate%3E2014-10-19%3C%2FStartDate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CEndDate%3E2021-10-08%3C%2FEndDate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CAmount%3E100%3C%2FAmount%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CBasePay%3E760%3C%2FBasePay%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CBonus%3E340%3C%2FBonus%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FRow%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CRow%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CEmployeeID%3E12345%3C%2FEmployeeID%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CRemote%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CStartDate%3E2017-10-10%3C%2FStartDate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CEndDate%3E2018-10-10%3C%2FEndDate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CAmount%3E250%3C%2FAmount%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CBasePay%3E1500%3C%2FBasePay%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CBonus%3E150%3C%2FBonus%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FRow%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CRow%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CEmployeeID%3E23456%3C%2FEmployeeID%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CRemote%3EN%3C%2FRemote%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CStartDate%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CEndDate%3E%3C%2FEndDate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CAmount%3E%3C%2FAmount%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CBasePay%3E1500%3C%2FBasePay%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CBonus%3E150%3C%2FBonus%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FRow%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CRow%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CEmployeeID%3E23456%3C%2FEmployeeID%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CRemote%3EN%3C%2FRemote%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CStartDate%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CEndDate%3E2020-10-10%3C%2FEndDate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CAmount%3E2400%3C%2FAmount%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CBasePay%3E1500%3C%2FBasePay%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CBonus%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FRow%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CRow%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CEmployeeID%3E23456%3C%2FEmployeeID%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CRemote%3EN%3C%2FRemote%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CStartDate%3E2018-10-24%3C%2FStartDate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CEndDate%3E2020-10-10%3C%2FEndDate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CAmount%3E2400%3C%2FAmount%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CBasePay%3E1500%3C%2FBasePay%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CBonus%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FRow%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CRow%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CEmployeeID%3E12345%3C%2FEmployeeID%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CRemote%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CStartDate%3E2017-10-10%3C%2FStartDate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CEndDate%3E2018-10-10%3C%2FEndDate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CAmount%3E350%3C%2FAmount%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CBasePay%3E1600%3C%2FBasePay%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CBonus%3E170%3C%2FBonus%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FRow%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CRow%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CEmployeeID%3E65432%3C%2FEmployeeID%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CRemote%3EY%3C%2FRemote%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CStartDate%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CEndDate%3E%3C%2FEndDate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CAmount%3E%3C%2FAmount%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CBasePay%3E1500%3C%2FBasePay%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CBonus%3E150%3C%2FBonus%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FRow%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CRow%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CEmployeeID%3E65432%3C%2FEmployeeID%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CRemote%3EY%3C%2FRemote%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CStartDate%3E2021-10-25%3C%2FStartDate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CEndDate%3E2020-10-10%3C%2FEndDate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CAmount%3E8400%3C%2FAmount%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CBasePay%3E1500%3C%2FBasePay%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CBonus%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FRow%3E%0D%0A%3C%2FRoot%3E&input-type=XML).

Comment: Thank you. Second solution you provided is somewhere close to getting desired output. But few of the elements on the result xml are empty for EmployeeIDs that appear multiple times on the input xml. For e.g. EmployeeID 23456, result xml produced using second solution you provided returns empty values for <StartDate> 
<EndDate><Amount> where as values do exist for <StartDate><EndDate><Amount> in the input xml. Could you please let me know what additional logic can be added to get desired output please?

Comment: @KM6895, well, the first `Row` with that `EmployeeID` being `23456` has those fields empty and most grouping approaches, including the one I have used, just output the first item (i.e. `Row` in this case) with all its children and omit duplicates items based on the key so the other `Row`s and their data are dropped. It seems you want to group to have a single `Row` but also merge the child data. Please explain in more details the criteria to populate the result `Row` if there are several `Row`s in a group.

Comment: Yes correct, group to have a single <Row> but also merge the child data. Grouping logic is based on Mobile set to Y or N. If elements under <Row> (with Mobile set to Y or N) are either empty or 0, check any child elements which are not empty or values greater than 0 for same <EmployeeID> and merge child elements. For e.g. <StartDate><EndDate><Amount> are empty for <EmployeeID> 23456, so merge child elements which have StartDate(i.e 2018-10-24) EndDate (i.e 2020-10-10) Amount(i.e. 2400).<Row> with <Mobile> is empty doesn't have to be grouped. e.g.12345 should appear twice on the result xml

Comment: @KM6895, check whether the added template helps. If you also have `0` instead of empty elements it might be necessary to change `<xsl:for-each-group select="key('group', (EmployeeID, true()))/*[node()]" group-by="node-name()">` to `<xsl:for-each-group select="key('group', (EmployeeID, true()))/*" group-by="node-name()"><xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[node()[not(. = '', '0')]]"/>`

Comment: The results that i am getting is not in XML format when using first template (  starting with <xsl:copy><xsl:for-each-group select="Row" composite="yes" group-by="EmployeeID, Remote = ('Y', 'N')">) and third template starting with   <xsl:template match="Root/Row[. intersect key('group', (EmployeeID, true()))[1]]">
I'm unable to figure out what is missing on this piece of code. Is there anything additionally i should be checking?

Comment: @KM6895, see whether the online sample helps that I have linked to in an edit of the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin, that worked. However, I encountered new situation while testing. Looks like <Row> needs to be grouped based on <Amount> as well because of one <EmployeeID> can have different values for <Amount> and those need to be grouped and merged separately. I created a new post  asking this question as I did not want to edit the original question to avoid any confusion for users who may be seeing this thread. Could you please let me know how to include <Amount> also to the grouping logic. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71453924/group-child-nodes-and-merge-child-data