# Group Child Nodes and Merge Child Data

Tags: group-by, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I’m trying to transform following XML using XSLT 3.0. Big Thanks to Martin Honnen for getting so far.

Can you please help me fix it please? Thank you.

Note: I can use XSLT 2.0 as well.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <Row>
        <EmployeeID>88888</EmployeeID>
        <Remote/>
        <StartDate>2014-10-19</StartDate>
        <EndDate>2021-10-08</EndDate>
        <Amount>100</Amount>
        <BasePay>760</BasePay>
        <Bonus>340</Bonus>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <EmployeeID>12345</EmployeeID>
        <Remote/>
        <StartDate>2017-10-10</StartDate>
        <EndDate>2018-10-10</EndDate>
        <Amount>250</Amount>
        <BasePay>1500</BasePay>
        <Bonus>150</Bonus>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <EmployeeID>23456</EmployeeID>
        <Remote>N</Remote>
        <StartDate/>
        <EndDate></EndDate>
        <Amount></Amount>
        <BasePay>1500</BasePay>
        <Bonus>150</Bonus>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <EmployeeID>23456</EmployeeID>
        <Remote>N</Remote>
        <StartDate/>
        <EndDate>2020-10-10</EndDate>
        <Amount>2400</Amount>
        <BasePay>1500</BasePay>
        <Bonus/>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <EmployeeID>23456</EmployeeID>
        <Remote>N</Remote>
        <StartDate>2018-10-24</StartDate>
        <EndDate>2020-10-10</EndDate>
        <Amount>2400</Amount>
        <BasePay>1500</BasePay>
        <Bonus/>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <EmployeeID>12345</EmployeeID>
        <Remote/>
        <StartDate>2017-10-10</StartDate>
        <EndDate>2018-10-10</EndDate>
        <Amount>350</Amount>
        <BasePay>1600</BasePay>
        <Bonus>170</Bonus>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <EmployeeID>65432</EmployeeID>
        <Remote>Y</Remote>
        <StartDate/>
        <EndDate></EndDate>
        <Amount></Amount>
        <BasePay>1500</BasePay>
        <Bonus>150</Bonus>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <EmployeeID>65432</EmployeeID>
        <Remote>Y</Remote>
        <StartDate>2021-10-25</StartDate>
        <EndDate>2020-10-10</EndDate>
        <Amount>8400</Amount>
        <BasePay>1500</BasePay>
        <Bonus/>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <EmployeeID>23456</EmployeeID>
        <Remote>N</Remote>
        <StartDate/>
        <EndDate></EndDate>
        <Amount></Amount>
        <BasePay>9200</BasePay>
        <Bonus>460</Bonus>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <EmployeeID>23456</EmployeeID>
        <Remote>N</Remote>
        <StartDate/>
        <EndDate>2022-01-01</EndDate>
        <Amount>7300</Amount>
        <BasePay>9200</BasePay>
        <Bonus/>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <EmployeeID>23456</EmployeeID>
        <Remote>N</Remote>
        <StartDate>2019-09-22</StartDate>
        <EndDate>2022-01-01</EndDate>
        <Amount>7300</Amount>
        <BasePay>9200</BasePay>
        <Bonus/>
    </Row>
</Root>
```

There are two types of records in this input XML

1. element with a value set to Y or N
2. element is empty

`<EmployeeID>` with same value can appear multiple times in the input file.

If element `<Remote>` with a value set to Y or N for an `<EmployeeID>`, it’s possible that same `<EmployeeID>` appears multiple times in input file.

Value of `<Remote>` will either be Y or N for one `<EmployeeID>`. However, element `<Amount>` can be different for one `<EmployeeID>` who appears multiple times on the record e.g. 23456

Result XML will need to be grouped to have single `<Row>` for one `<EmployeeID>` and merge the child data of same `<EmployeeID>` **who has same value for element** `<Amount>`

**For e.g. 23456**

Output XML should have two `<EmployeeID>`  23456 under `<Row>` because value of `<Amount>` is different even though `<EmployeeID>` is same. First occurrence of `<EmployeeID>` should have value of `<Amount>` 2400 and second occurrence of `<EmployeeID>`  23456 should have value of `<Amount>` 7300 – This part is partially working because result XML returns only one occurrence of `<EmployeeID>` 23456

**For e.g. 12345**

Output XML should have two `<EmployeeID>`  12345 under `<Row>` because value of `<Amount>` is different even though `<EmployeeID>` is same.  First occurrence of `<EmployeeID>` 12345 should have value of 250 for `<Amount>` and second occurrence of `<EmployeeID>`  12345 should have value of 350 for  – This part is already working with the attempted XSLT given below. No change is needed.

**Expected Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <Row>
        <EmployeeID>88888</EmployeeID>
        <Remote/>
        <StartDate>2014-10-19</StartDate>
        <EndDate>2021-10-08</EndDate>
        <Amount>100</Amount>
        <BasePay>760</BasePay>
        <Bonus>340</Bonus>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <EmployeeID>12345</EmployeeID>
        <Remote/>
        <StartDate>2017-10-10</StartDate>
        <EndDate>2018-10-10</EndDate>
        <Amount>250</Amount>
        <BasePay>1500</BasePay>
        <Bonus>150</Bonus>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <EmployeeID>23456</EmployeeID>
        <Remote>N</Remote>
        <StartDate>2018-10-24</StartDate>
        <EndDate>2020-10-10</EndDate>
        <Amount>2400</Amount>
        <BasePay>1500</BasePay>
        <Bonus>150</Bonus>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <EmployeeID>12345</EmployeeID>
        <Remote/>
        <StartDate>2017-10-10</StartDate>
        <EndDate>2018-10-10</EndDate>
        <Amount>350</Amount>
        <BasePay>1600</BasePay>
        <Bonus>170</Bonus>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <EmployeeID>65432</EmployeeID>
        <Remote>Y</Remote>
        <StartDate>2021-10-25</StartDate>
        <EndDate>2020-10-10</EndDate>
        <Amount>8400</Amount>
        <BasePay>1500</BasePay>
        <Bonus>150</Bonus>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <EmployeeID>23456</EmployeeID>
        <Remote>N</Remote>
        <StartDate>2019-09-22</StartDate>
        <EndDate>2022-01-01</EndDate>
        <Amount>7300</Amount>
        <BasePay>9200</BasePay>
        <Bonus>460</Bonus>
    </Row>
</Root>
```

**Current XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes">
    
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    
    <xsl:key name="group" match="Root/Row" composite="yes" use="EmployeeID, Remote = ('Y', 'N')"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="Root/Row[. intersect key('group', (EmployeeID, true()))[position() > 1]]"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="Root/Row[. intersect key('group', (EmployeeID, true()))[1]]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="key('group', (EmployeeID, true()))/*[node()]" group-by="node-name()">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Current Output** - Second Occurrence of `<EmployeeID>`23456 is missing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <Row>
        <EmployeeID>88888</EmployeeID>
        <Remote/>
        <StartDate>2014-10-19</StartDate>
        <EndDate>2021-10-08</EndDate>
        <Amount>100</Amount>
        <BasePay>760</BasePay>
        <Bonus>340</Bonus>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <EmployeeID>12345</EmployeeID>
        <Remote/>
        <StartDate>2017-10-10</StartDate>
        <EndDate>2018-10-10</EndDate>
        <Amount>250</Amount>
        <BasePay>1500</BasePay>
        <Bonus>150</Bonus>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <EmployeeID>23456</EmployeeID>
        <Remote>N</Remote>
        <StartDate>2018-10-24</StartDate>
        <EndDate>2020-10-10</EndDate>
        <Amount>2400</Amount>
        <BasePay>1500</BasePay>
        <Bonus>150</Bonus>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <EmployeeID>12345</EmployeeID>
        <Remote/>
        <StartDate>2017-10-10</StartDate>
        <EndDate>2018-10-10</EndDate>
        <Amount>350</Amount>
        <BasePay>1600</BasePay>
        <Bonus>170</Bonus>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <EmployeeID>65432</EmployeeID>
        <Remote>Y</Remote>
        <StartDate>2021-10-25</StartDate>
        <EndDate>2020-10-10</EndDate>
        <Amount>8400</Amount>
        <BasePay>1500</BasePay>
        <Bonus>150</Bonus>
    </Row>
</Root>
```

Comment: The data seems rather complicated, in theory to add an additional grouping key you should be able to use e.g. `use="EmployeeID, Remote = ('Y', 'N'), Amount"`. However, your data has empty `Amount` element which based on your wanted result you don't want to output as different `Amount` to form its own result `Row` but somehow want to merge or ignore. Based on that variety of the data it is hard to come up with a precise and working grouping approach.

Comment: First thing I have tried is adding Amount to the group key logic which hasn't returned accurate results but rather messed up previously working solution that you provided. Any further suggestions that you can provide please ? Thanks

Comment: Your criteria are not clear to me, sometimes it seems you want to group all `Row` elements based on `EmployeeID`, sometimes it seems you want to group only the `Row` elements with `Remote` being `Y` or `N` on `EmployeeID`. Additionally there are various `Row`s with `Amount` being empty, it is not clear how they are to be treated if you also say you want to distinguish or group based on `Amount`. Let's wait whether someone else with fresh eyes comes along and can make more sense of your requirements.

Comment: Ok, sure. Thanks!